# Module not found: crypto for the sake of using cognito for user management

Tags: stream, amazon-cognito, node-modules, cryptojs

Hello everyone im trying to setup a cognito + tableau SSO feature in my app, with session management and all, and im stuck with this bug where it dosent seem to find the crypto module i need for the cognito configuration.
i get the following error a couple of times:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Pangea-Projects\InsightsSolutionElections\src\routes\LoginScreen'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

and it also throws me the same error just with the "stream" module instead of the "crypto"

Things i tried to fix:

1. i created webpack.config.js and this its contents:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // Set your entry point. Adjust the path to the entry file if needed.
  entry: './src/index.js',
  // Set the output configuration. This will generate a bundle.js file in the 'dist' folder.
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  // Set the fallback configuration for 'crypto' module.
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "crypto-browserify": require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
      "crypto": false
    }
  }
};
```

2. i created config.overrides.js and this is its contents:

```
const { fallback } = require('crypto-browserify');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    // Add the 'crypto' module fallback
    config.resolve.fallback = fallback;

    return config;
  },
};
```

3. i configured package.json so it runs with the react-app-rewired so the configurations of the webpackage would take place this is its content:

```
{
 "name": "demo-reactapp",
 "version": "0.1.1",
 "private": true,
 "config-overrides-path": "config.overrides.js",
 "dependencies": {
   "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^5.0.7",
   "@formatjs/intl": "^2.7.2",
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
   "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
   "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
   "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.1",
   "aws-amplify": "^5.3.6",
   "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
   "crypto": "^1.0.1",
   "i18next": "^22.4.15",
   "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.1",
   "i18next-http-backend": "^2.2.0",
   "insights-tableau": "github:pangea-it/insights-tableau",
   "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
   "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
   "react": "^18.2.0",
   "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
   "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
   "react-i18next": "^12.2.2",
   "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
   "react-intl": "^6.4.2",
   "react-router": "^6.4.2",
   "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
   "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
   "react-select": "^5.7.3",
   "reactstrap": "^9.1.9",
   "scss": "^0.2.4",
   "semantic-ui-css": "^2.5.0",
   "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.4",
   "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
   "test": "react-app-rewired test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": [
     "react-app",
     "react-app/jest"
   ]
 },
 "browserslist": {
   "production": [
     ">0.2%",
     "not dead",
     "not op_mini all"
   ],
   "development": [
     "last 1 chrome version",
     "last 1 firefox version",
     "last 1 safari version"
   ]
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "assert": "^2.0.0",
   "buffer": "^6.0.3",
   "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
   "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
   "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
   "process": "^0.11.10",
   "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
   "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
   "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
   "url": "^0.11.1",
   "webpack": "^5.88.2"
 }
}
```

4. deleted all node modules and reinstalled, reinstalled all the dependencies mentioned above.

it (the computer) also tried to look for the config.overrides.js file inside the node modules folder inside the react-app-rewired when i tried to npm start it and it didnt start but i managed to fix that and start the app, but maybe i should just put the config file where it looked for it, im not sure if it will make it worse or better so im asking this here aswell.

basically i really need to solve this bug.

Thanks in advance!